# Copy data from workbook sheets to different workbooks with the same sheet name

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet

I want to copy the data from multiple tabs in one main workbook to individual workbooks with the same tab name.

For example, every month I receive a source file that has data in sheets "5532, 6789, 4325, 9999". I want to copy all the data in each sheet to a correlating workbook based on the same tab name.

Main file:
[image]

Correlating file:
[image]

Is it possible to open the main workbook and copy the data from each cost center tab in the main workbook to the correlating cost center workbook, such as copying the data from tab 5532 to workbook CC_5532?
Sheets from both workbooks have the same names.

This is my code to open all the individual cost center workbooks.

```vb
Sub CopyandPasteDataFromWBs()

'reference variables for main wb
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim file As Variant
Dim mwb As Workbook

'Current Directory of folder
ChDir ("C:\Users\user55\OneDrive - DummyOrg Inc\Documents\Working Files")

'loop through each org
Dim orgcount As Integer
For orgcount = 1 To 4

    'Open file dialoge
    file = Application.GetOpenFilename

    'stop loop if user cancels
    If file = False Then
        Exit For
    End If

Next
End Sub
```

I need advice or support on next steps.

Comment: It is possible to do this. But! The time you use to develope this, you could use to learn Excels "Get&Transform Data" (Power Query), which can do this without programming skills. Just to know where to click. Check youtube "power query consolidate" (the data you stack together is then good for analysis, like pivot tables and so on, not for editing)